# Is using input() in an if statement a bad practice?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, input

I was just curious whether or not it is a bad practice to do something like this:

```
if input("Continue? Enter yes or no: ").lower() == "yes":
    # Continue code
else:
    # Else code
```

I kind of like this because you don't need to create a whole new variable, but is this frowned upon for any reason? If it is not bad in this example, are there other cases where it would be bad? I haven't really seen any examples of this, so I'm not sure.

Comment: This question is a bit too subjective, but there's nothing "wrong" with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question is, why is a problem to create a new name if it will make things clearer and easily maintainable? What if you need to do a more complex validation in the future? And what if you need to work more on the user input than just lowering it?

Of course, there is nothing wrong with your code but it just works if the user types yes or no. But, what happens if the user types some invalid data? Then you will need some name to bind to your user input:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Type yes or no: ").lower()
    if user_input == 'yes':
        # Do something
    elif user_input == 'no':
        # Don't do something
    else:
        continue
```

Otherwise, which what would you compare with 'no' in the elif statement? In your example, if the user types "Hell yes, I want to spam with eggs and spam spam!!!" he will not get a nice breakfast.

Your question could raises a lot of points, these are mines. But check what else will appear here, because, certainly, it will help you to make better code in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bad practice. Saving a variable really doesn't save you anything. Variables are tools to help you do your job. Don't avoid things that make your job easier.

One of the biggest benefits to using a variable is that it's easier to use a debugger because you can set a breakpoint between the input statement and the conditional. it also makes the code easier to test because you can temporarily replace the input statement with something else, without potentially introducing a bug in the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it not a good idea to code like this, because if you want to add some other things about the user's input like this:

`if input("Continue? Enter yes or no: ").lower().strip().replace("[","").replace("]","") == "yes":`

your code will be too long and not easy to read it.